# JavaScript Infinite Slider

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I'm experiencing an issue with the slider. When scrolling to the right, it halts at the right edge. Despite having utilized a similar structure in a previous instance where it worked correctly, in this case, the scrolling stops at the right edge.

```
function infiniteScroll() {
  const { scrollLeft, scrollWidth, offsetWidth } = carousel;
  if (scrollLeft === 0) {
    carousel.classList.add("no-transition");
    carousel.scrollTo({ left: scrollWidth - 2 * offsetWidth });
    carousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
  } else if (Math.ceil(scrollLeft) >= scrollWidth - offsetWidth) {
    carousel.classList.add("no-transition");
    carousel.scrollTo({ left: offsetWidth });
    carousel.classList.remove("no-transition");
  }
}
```

I attempted to modify the scrolling conditions to reach the right edge, but the slider is not detecting the right edge.

`Math.ceil(scrollLeft) >= scrollWidth - offsetWidth`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.